# Removing the loops (for, while) in Python

Tags: python, math

There is a code that calculates after how many years the deposit amount will reach the target amount, taking into account the specified interest rate (the fractional part is discarded).

```
deposit_amount = int(input('Input deposit amount: '))
annual_percentage = int(input('input annual percentage: '))
final_amount = int(input('Input final amount: '))
year = 0

while deposit_amount < final_amount:
  year += 1
  deposit_amount = deposit_amount * (100 + annual_percentage) // 100

print('After', year, 'years the amount will be:', deposit_amount)
```

Question: How to solve the same problem without using cycles? They gave a hint that you can use the "math" library.

Comment: Just use plain math (algebra) before you using the `math` library to implement your formula.

Comment: Just use the compound interest formula: `A = P(1 + r / n ) nt`, where `A` is the Final Amount, `P` is the Initial Principal, `r` is the Annual Interest Rate, `n` is the Number of compounding periods per year, and `t` is the Number of years. As Julien said, just use plain algebra.

Comment: @accdias thank you! Below I have published the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Julien and accdias thank you!

Everything would be fine, but according to the condition of the problem, the answer should not be the sum, after n the number of periods, but the number of periods (n). While studying compound interest, I came across logarithms and solved the problem using them using the math library. Most likely, my teacher meant exactly this decision:

```
deposit_amount = int(input('Input deposit amount: '))
annual_percentage = int(input('input annual percentage: '))
final_amount = int(input('Input final amount: '))

years = ceil(log(final_amount / deposit_amount, annual_percentage))

print('After', years, 'years, your investments will reach the goal and amount to', 
      round(deposit_amount * annual_percentage**years), 'coins.')
```

Comment: If you didn't understand what we said about the formula, I guess you also don't understand the solution you posted is an application of that very same formula, which leads us to infer that you need to go back and learn a bit more about compound interest, and algebra in general.

Comment: @accdias Everything is fine, you correctly pushed me to study compound interest and this formula. I just took algebra more than 20 years ago and didn't use it in practice until I started learning Python Basic. Thank you very much again. I will repeat the knowledge forgotten a long time ago. Without your suggestions, it would be several times more difficult to solve this problem.